# Why does this parallel code in D scale so badly?

Tags: c++, performance, parallel-processing, d

Here is one experiment I performed comparing parallelism in C++ and D. I implemented an algorithm (a parallel label propagation scheme for community detection in networks) in both languages, using the same design: A parallel iterator gets a handle function (normally a closure) and applies it for every node in the graph.

Here is the iterator in D, implemented using `taskPool` from `std.parallelism`:

```
/**
 * Iterate in parallel over all nodes of the graph and call handler (lambda closure).
 */
void parallelForNodes(F)(F handle) {
    foreach (node v; taskPool.parallel(std.range.iota(z))) {
        // call here
        handle(v);
    }
}
```

And this is the handle function which is passed:

```
    auto propagateLabels = (node v){
        if (active[v] && (G.degree(v) > 0)) {
            integer[label] labelCounts;

            G.forNeighborsOf(v, (node w) {
                label lw = labels[w];
                labelCounts[lw] += 1; // add weight of edge {v, w}
            });

            // get dominant label
            label dominant;
            integer lcmax = 0;
            foreach (label l, integer lc; labelCounts) {
                if (lc > lcmax) {
                    dominant = l;
                    lcmax = lc;
                }
            }

        if (labels[v] != dominant) { // UPDATE
            labels[v] = dominant;
            nUpdated += 1; // TODO: atomic update?
            G.forNeighborsOf(v, (node u) {
                active[u] = 1;
            });
        } else {
            active[v] = 0;
        }

        }
    };
```

The C++11 implementation is almost identical, but uses OpenMP for parallelization. So what do the scaling experiments show?

[image: scaling]

Here I examine weak scaling, doubling the input graph size while also doubling the number of threads and measuring the running time. The ideal would be a straight line, but of course there is some overhead for parallelism. I use `defaultPoolThreads(nThreads)` in my main function to set the number of threads for the D program. The curve for C++ looks good, but the curve for D looks surprisingly bad. Am I doing something wrong w.r.t. D parallelism, or does this reflect badly on the scalability of parallel D programs?

p.s. compiler flags

for D: `rdmd -release -O -inline -noboundscheck`

for C++: `-std=c++11 -fopenmp -O3 -DNDEBUG`

pps. Something must be really wrong, because the D implementation is slower in parallel than sequentially:

[image]

ppps. For the curious, here are the Mercurial clone urls for both implementations:

- http://algohub.iti.kit.edu/parco/Prototypes/PLPd
- http://algohub.iti.kit.edu/parco/Prototypes/PLPcpp

Comment: What does the performance look like if you did it without openmp?

Comment: From checking around it doesn't look like the dmd compiler currently supports openmp. It doesn't seem like an apples-to-apples comparsion to me if one version uses openmp and other version doesn't.

Comment: @greatwolf Unless I misunderstand you, I believe you are missing the point. D does not have OpenMP, but it has the `std.parallelism` library, which does provide similar parallel constructs. In fact, the D program uses many cores when running.

Comment: False sharing, maybe? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing

Comment: How many cores do you have? Lots of people think parallel = speed. Only under carefully constructed circumstances, and you certainly can't do any better than the number of processors you have.

Comment: Can you try compiling the D program under GDC?

Comment: @MikeDunlavey 16 physical cores, 32 parallel threads show up in htop. The algorithm is embarrassingly parallel, so here parallel = speed, as demonstrated by the C++ implementation.

Comment: What's the y axis on those graphs?  Time?  Throughput?  Speedup?  I guess you did say you were measuring time, so I'll assume that's what you graphed.

Comment: @BenVoigt running time in seconds (or milliseconds for the 2nd plot)

Comment: I can confirm your findings. The more threads I use, the longer it runs: Platform Win32. I know you used 64bit (because I had to change some 'long' to 'size_t' to compile it). Are you using Win or Nix ?

Comment: @MichalMinich Thanks for the confirmation. We are using Linux.

Answer (score 8):

It's hard to say because I don't fully understand how your algorithm is supposed to work, but it looks like your code is not thread-safe, which is causing the algorithm to run more iterations than necessary.

I added this to the end of `PLP.run`:

```
writeln(nIterations);
```

With 1 thread `nIterations = 19`
With 10 threads `nIterations = 34`
With 100 threads `nIterations = 90`

So as you can see, it's taking longer not because of some issues with `std.parallelism`, but simply because it's doing more work.

Why is your code not thread-safe?

The function you run in parallel is `propagateLabels`, which has **shared, unsynchronised** access to `labels`, `nUpdated`, and `active`. Who knows what bizarre behaviour this is causing, but it can't be good.

Before you start profiling, you need to fix the algorithm to be thread-safe.

Comment: Good observation. The interesting question to me is: Why is this behavior so different in D from the virtually identical C++ implementation? I am aware that threads share `labels`, `active` and `nUpdated`. This situation is the same for the C++/OpenMP implementation, where it is not a problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with OpenMP, but the way it farms out jobs may be different from std.parallelism, so maybe the OpenMP solution "just works" with the way you are running things.

Answer (score 5):

As Peter Alexander points out, your algorithm appears to be thread-unsafe.  To make it thread-safe, you need to eliminate all data dependencies between events that may occur in different threads simultaneously or in an undefined order.  One way to do this is to replicate some state across threads using `WorkerLocalStorage` (provided in std.parallelism), and possibly merge the results in a relatively cheap loop at the end of your algorithm.

In some cases the process of replicating this state can be automated by writing the algorithm as a reduction and using `std.parallelism.reduce` (possibly in combination with `std.algorithm.map` or `std.parallelism.map`) to do the heavy lifting.